# How to bind an td contenteditable value to ng-model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, contenteditable

Hi i have the following td element:

```
<td ng-model="name" contenteditable='true'></td>
```

Is there anyway I can pass this ng-model value from the contenteditable td to my controller? Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binding to `contenteditable` isn't built in, but you can write a simple directive that will accomplish the task.

```js
app.directive("contenteditable", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

      function read() {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html());
      }

      ngModel.$render = function() {
        element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || "");
      };

      element.bind("blur keyup change", function() {
        scope.$apply(read);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Take note, however, that in Internet Explorer, `contenteditable` cannot be applied to the `TABLE`, `COL`, `COLGROUP`, `TBODY`, `TD`, `TFOOT`, `TH`, `THEAD`, or `TR` elements directly; a content editable `SPAN` or `DIV` element would need to be placed inside the individual table cells (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533690(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Am sorry am bit new to angularJS. What is directive? Is it a function inside my controller?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.  Directives are custom code that can be used just like Controllers to add custom behaviors to your HTML.

Comment: Thanks a lot Claies. what is actually the `restrict: "A"` and `require: "ngModel",` means?

Comment: `restrict: "A"` means that the directive matches an HTML Attribute (`contenteditable`, in this case.)  The `require: "ngModel"` means that the directive expects there to be an `ng-model` attribute present on the same HTML element as the directive, since it manipulates the value of `ng-model`.

Comment: Thats great! Thanks Claies!

Answer (score 1):

**1. With angular-contenteditable**

Use angular-contenteditable https://github.com/akatov/angular-contenteditable.

That can get value from contenteditable elements

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <span contenteditable="true"
        ng-model="model"
        strip-br="true"
        strip-tags="true"
        select-non-editable="true">
  </span>
</div>
```

**2.With Directive**

As well as you can use this [Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for it.

This Directive was initially obtained : http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/V4axn/

```js
angular.module('customControl', []).
  directive('contenteditable', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
      require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        if(!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

        // Specify how UI should be updated
        ngModel.$render = function() {
          element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
        };

        // Listen for change events to enable binding
        element.on('blur keyup change', function() {
          scope.$apply(read);
        });
        read(); // initialize

        // Write data to the model
        function read() {
          var html = element.html();
          // When we clear the content editable the browser leaves a <br> behind
          // If strip-br attribute is provided then we strip this out
          if( attrs.stripBr && html == '<br>' ) {
            html = '';
          }
          ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="customControl">
  <form name="myForm">
   <div contenteditable
        name="myWidget" ng-model="userContent"
        strip-br="true"
        required>Change me!</div>
    <span ng-show="myForm.myWidget.$error.required">Required!</span>
   <hr>
   <textarea ng-model="userContent"></textarea>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to download that package DInindu?

Comment: @vellattukudy yeah you should, Although you can easily use Directive that i provided

Comment: Thanks DININDU! Appreciate that!