# Enabling Contenteditable with Ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I want to enable Contenteditable in table when user click on button. Thank you.

```
$<tbody context-menu="menuOptions" model="{{podelaRedova}}">    
    <tr dir-paginate="us in zdravstveniPostupci |  filter: {Postupak: nasUser} | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort | itemsPerPage:selectedMenu" ng-dblclick="updateOsoba(us,     selectMjesto )" on-long-press="updateOsoba(us, selectMjesto )" ng-click="odaberiOsobe(us,$index)">
        <td ng-repeat="key in draggableObjects" ng-if="key.visible">
            <span ng-if="key.name!='Mjesta'" contenteditable="false">{{us[key.name]}}</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

<div class="col-md-4 center-block" style="position: fixed; top: 36%; left: 82%;" id="gumbicc">
    <button type="button" class="btn  btn-responsive" ng-model="button" ng-init="button = true">{{HrvatskiPrevod.jezik[OdabraniJEZIKdef].UrediTablicu}}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: see this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312473/how-to-bind-an-td-contenteditable-value-to-ng-model

Comment: This one too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583651/contenteditable-with-ng-model-doesnt-work